# Does $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$ converge in $(X=(0, \infty),d)$ where $d(x,y)=|ln(\frac{x}{y})|$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Does $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$ converge in $(X=(0, \infty),d)$ where $d(x,y)=|ln(\frac{x}{y})|$?

Intuitively I guess that the sequence is heading towards $0$ for large $n$ so if it were to converge it would have to converge to $0$ but $0 \notin X$ so the sequence does not converge in $(X,d)$ what is a formal way to express this though?

Thanks!

Comment: "what is a formal way to express this though?" Fix any $x$ in $X$ and show that $d(x_n,x)$ *does not* converge to $0$.

Comment: But that would only show that $(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $0$ it could potentially converge to something else right?

Comment: $X$ being complete, $
d(x_{2n},x_n)=\left|\ln(n/(2n)) \right|=\ln 2 \nrightarrow 0.
$

Comment: No, that would mean that $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x$, **for every $x$ in $X$**, which is equivalent to saying that $(x_n)$ diverges.

Comment: @Did I misread you comment sorry it makes sense now thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that there exist $l>0$ such that $x_n \to l$ in the topology given by $d$. This would mean that $d(l, x_n) \to 0$, which is equivalent to $\ln (nl) \to 0$, which is impossible, therefore that sequence is not convergent in the topology of $d$.